# How to pass VM arguments from launch.json to Junit Test class in VSCode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, mockito, junit5, jmockit

I am trying to mock a static method using JMockit. The combination that I'm trying to run is Junit5, Jmockit 1.41 and JDK11 with VSCode. Initially I got `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Running on JDK 9 requires -javaagent:<proper path>/jmockit-1.n.jar or -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf` while running it on STS. I solved this problem by passing `-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf` as vm argument in STS. This works fine with STS.

However, when I try to run the same source code in VSCode, it threw the same error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Running on JDK 9 requires -javaagent:<proper path>/jmockit-1.n.jar or -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf`. So I edited `java.jdt.ls.vmargs` key and added `-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf` as value in settings.json file in VSCode. But it didn't work. I tried to add VMArgs in launch.json also. The error still persists. I tried to add `-javaagent` in argline tag through pom.xml as a plugin. But nothing seems to be working.

PS: I have tried using `-javaagent` in settings.json. It's also not working. The code(A simple static method with bare minimum code) works fine with STS. How to make it work with VSCode?

Can anyone suggest how to pass vmargs form launch.json to Junit Test class? Is there any alternative?

Comment: maybe you could try to use `task.json` to pass the arguments,refer to [JUnit tasks.json](https://gist.github.com/felixfbecker/1b03770e83bf795ebde8)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what I was doing wrong. In settings.json file I was trying to pass `-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf` argument in `java.jdt.ls.vmargs`. However, this won't work for Junit test cases. In order to pass jvm args for Junit test cases, need to create a separate key called `java.test.config`. Refer VSCode documentation for Junit.

That solved the problem for me.

Comment: I added `-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf` in `vmargs` under `java.test.config` but that did not make any difference. Need help!